# Why does a "on a non-object" error occurs with this extension in Magento?

Tags: magento

I'm having an Issue with a blog extension in Magento CE 1.6.2.0.

1. I installed this extension: [Neotheme_nBlog](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/nblog-blog-extension-by-neotheme.html).
2. I created an entry in the administrator.
3. Then I went to http://www.example.com/index.php/blog/ to see the recently created entry.
4. What I saw was an error like this:

   Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object
   in /home/example.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/caramel/template/magicat/left.phtml
5. I searched in google the terms: `"template/magicat/left.phtml" getName` and what I only found is sites having this issue, but no support at all.

**Please note**: I know what does that error mean in PHP ("unfortunately" I'm not new at that). What I don't understand is what's happening with such [**NON**/null] object and **how to fix it without killing a dozen of kittens**.

**Question**: What can I do to solve it? What is the nature of the error, regarding Magento?(again: not PHP).

**Notes**: The Magento site (http://magento.stackexchange.com) is somewhat poor and strict to bring support of such nature, so asking there is **not** an option.

**Edit** (as answer to comment, and to clarify):

- Neotheme is still not responding the request.
- Don't know what should I look on such file (instances are not initialized there, but only accessed).
- I'm using the *default* theme (caramel), which has esthetical changes (does not have layout changes).

Comment: From administration clear the cache and recompile (if using compilation).  Can you recreate the problem with the default Magento theme?  Have you looked at the file mentioned to see what is going on?  Have you tried contacting "Neotheme" to see if they can help too?

Comment: This is just happening to me *now*. It happened many hours before. Did not get any support yet from neotheme. I'm not using compilation (using compilation in Magento CE makes every extension break - so in order to be able to install the extensions and not get any Class Not Found error anymore, I disabled compilation). How do I "look at the file mentioned"? It only tried to acces a variable (block instantiation is not done in views)

Comment: AND I cannot recreate the probme with the default theme because the default is caramel and the former developers of this distribution *killed an insane amount of cats* (they did not alter layout.xml files, though) - I'm actually using the "caramel", which has not the esthetics of caramel

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your system specifically, but on this

```
template/magicat/left.phtml
```

It looks like you've added a template named `magicat/left.phtml` to your system -- either via an extension or custom development.  Somewhere in this file PHP's called `getName` on a non-object.  There's a variety of reasons this could be happening, and without seeing the specific line of code PHP's complaining about in your system, it's hard to say.  It'd also be helpful to know if `magicat` is part of the extension or something else.

The most common reason for this error in a template is code that relies on a block being there that's been removed by another extension (eitehr via layout XML or observer methods)

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('some_block')->getName();
```

The next most common is people using the registry to communicate between templates and views, but a registry key not being set

```
Mage::registry('some_item')->getName();
```

Without knowing the variable and context, it's doubtful anyone will be able to help you.